# Automate two commands in sequence on login (Killing Nemo)

Tags: unity, command-line, nautilus

In a June4 reply on an askubuntu post regarding

When Cinnamon is installed, Unity desktop “smears” (doesn't refresh) and shows no wallpaper

madrang wrote that:
 There is no need to purge cinnamon. You just need to kill nemo and start nautilus instead. $ killall nemo $ nautilus –  madrang Jun 4 at 4:45

Well, the answer Was brilliant, and it works for me 'as-is'; however, I find I have to perform the same two commands every time I reboot my computer.
I'm an intermittent Ubuntu Unity (AND Cinnamon) user, converting my system to these two environments full time. I suspect I only need to load Nautilus for the Unity desktop, since Cinnamon appeared to work properly before:
Is there a way that anyone knows of to automate or default to this condition as soon as I log into the Unity Environment (Trusty)?
If so, HOW?

Thanks for your time,

CS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set nautilus as the default for the desktop and file manager:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Comment: *ctrl+o* to save.

Comment: I'm fairly sure `rc.local` will fire off well before X has even started. I'd dump that part of the answer.